# I have two queries one works one doesn't using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I am creating a movie database and I have a query that finds movies by their ID and it is working.

```
public function getMovieById($id) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id = ?";
        $paramType = "i";
        $paramValue = array(
            $id
        );
        
        $result = $this->db_handle->runQuery($query, $paramType, $paramValue);
        return $result;
    }
```

I then tried to make a query that would search for movies by title.  So if I entered say "Alien" it would return any movies I own with the word "Alien in title.  No matter what I have tried I get nothing returned and no errors.

```
public function getMovieByTitle ($title) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE ?";
        $paramType = "s";
        $paramValue = array(
            $title
        );

        $result = $this->db_handle->runQuery($query, $paramType, $paramValue);
        return $result;
    }
```

Any points in the right direction is appreciated

I also tried a function to see if title is being passed by $_POST and it shows it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatinate `%` which works as placeholder for an number of characters in sql  in the php code

```
public function getMovieByTitle ($title) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE ?";
        $paramType = "s";
        $paramValue = array(
          "%".  $title . "%"
        );

        $result = $this->db_handle->runQuery($query, $paramType, $paramValue);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you GMB and nbk that is what I needed.  I was able to look that up and learn about it appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a value such as `'Alien'` to the `LIKE` operator does not do what you expect.

This predicate...

```
WHERE title LIKE 'Alien'
```

... Actually behaves similarly as:

```
WHERE title = 'Alien'
```

If you want to seach for titles that **contain** a given string, you need to use `'%'`, the wildcard character :

```
WHERE title LIKE '%Alien%'
```

You can either concatenate the percent sign in your code then inject it in the query, or pass the original value to the query and add the wildcard in SQL:

```
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```